# Problemas para ejecutar un archivo compilado en VS Code

Tags: c

Estoy empezando a programar en VS Code con C/C++ y tengo un problema, resulta que estoy usando MinGW para compilar mis programas y VS Code para escribirlos, cuando creo archivos con la extension .c y no tengo problemas, pero cuanod creo archivos con la extension .cpp para archivos de C++, tenog que cambiar las configuraciones de compilacion y utilizar gcc para que todo compile sin errores, pero el problema es que cuando se crea el archivo ejecutable de algun programa en C++, me aparece este mensaje:

[image: Mensaje de error]

Realmente no entiendo porque aparece esto si cuando compilo los archivos de C si funcionan, espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias

Comment: Con tan poca información es difícil ayudarte. ¿Cómo tienes configurado el IDE? ¿Cómo estás compilando?

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, donde deberia de revisar lo que me estas diciendo? porque soy nuevo programando y no conosco mucho sobre las configuraciones de VS Code ni tampoco de MinGW

Comment: Intenta describir los pasos que seguiste para compilarlo y si modificaste alguna configuración. De lo contrario debería estar por defecto.